# How can I store my picture from react in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, upload, google-cloud-storage

Hey I try to store a picture uploaded by a user in my Firebase storage.

But I don't how to access to the file because when I send with AJAX my picture, I receive in Node this : blob:http://localhost:3000/f64a37b5-ec9f-4b99-8784-0fe7842e22da.

And when I try to send it that doesn't works.

I put the code below :

React part -->

```js
uploadPicture(file) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
    console.log(file[0])
    fetch('/upload_picture', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
          "picture": file[0]
      })
    })
}
```

The console.log(file[0]) render me that :

```js
File(330479)
  {preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/c128fe5d-db61-4caa-8851-95e397b67e6a", name: "Capture d’écran 2018-07-27 à 11.34.01.png", lastModified: 1532684046000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 27 2018 11:34:06 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), webkitRelativePath: "", …}

  lastModified: 1532684046000
  
  lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 27 2018 11:34:06 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) {}
  
  name: "Capture d’écran 2018-07-27 à 11.34.01.png"
  
  preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/c128fe5d-db61-4caa-8851-95e397b67e6a"
  
  size: 330479
  
  type: "image/png"
  
  webkitRelativePath: ""
  
  __proto__: File
```

Express -->

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const firebase = require('firebase')
const googleStorage = require('@google-cloud/storage')

const storage = googleStorage({
    projectId: "-------ha",
    keyFilename: "-------------------------WTY"
})

const bucket = storage.bucket("gs://------ha.appspot.com")

router.post('/upload_picture', (req, res) => {
    const file = req.body.picture.preview
    console.log(file)
    bucket.upload(file, function(err, file) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(`${file} add to firebase`)
        }
        else
            console.log('Error')
      });
})
```

The console.log(file) render me : blob:http://localhost:3000/f64a27b5-ec9f-4b99-8784-0fe7842e22da

And this render me 'Error' when I upload a file.

Someone know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the Firebase JavaScript SDK so you can upload images directly from your react front end to your cloud storage instead of passing the images to your node server (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start). Start by installing Firebase into your react project.

```
 npm install --save firebase
```

Then configure Firebase with the appropriate settings and upload directly from react.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var config = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

 // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
var storage = firebase.storage();
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
var exampleRef = storageRef.child('example.jpg');

var file = ... // use the Blob or File 
exampleRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

Comment: I don't use firebase as a database. So I don't have a database url. I use localhost and I read that we have to use googlecloud-storage if we haven't a firebase domain name. Is it true ?